# Check if a bit is set only once in a series of bitsets

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am trying to find the way what is the correct approach to achieve this:
Imagine that we have a group of bit sets as following:

```
00100
00101
10000
00010
10001
```

I would like to test, which of the bits are only set once in all the bitsets. In the example, the result would be:

```
00010
```

since the 4th bit is the only one that appears only once in all series.

Which would be the best approach by doing bitwise logical operations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm very curious about the shortest possible answer to this. I can think of several ways to achieve this, but I'm trying to formulate a one-liner operation.

Comment: if you know the series beforehand: transpose it and look for a power of 2 : that will point which column(s) has only 1 bit set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the once-twice approach:

- for each collection

  - for each element

    - if the element is in the `once` set

      - add it to the `twice` set
    - else

      - add it to the `once` set
- return `once` - `twice`

The trick here is that it can be performed in parallel:

- for each collection `C`

  - `twice` := `twice` OR (`once` AND `C`)
  - `once` := `once` OR `C`

The implementation could look like:

```
BitSet once = new BitSet();
BitSet twice = new BitSet();
for(BitSet b : sets){
  BitSet mask = (BitSet) b.clone();
  mask.and(once);
  twice.or(mask);
  once.or(b);
}
once.andNot(twice);
return once;
```

Answer (score 11):

As you can see you cannot do it using a single set for storing intermediate results, because you need to distinguish between 3 states for each bit: never set, set once and set more than once.

So, you need at least 2 intermediate results. For example, you can track bits set at least once and bits set more than once separately:

```
int atLeastOnce = 0;
int moreThanOnce = 0;
for (int current: sets) {
    moreThanOnce |= (atLeastOnce & current);
    atLeastOnce |= current;
}
int justOnce = atLeastOnce & ~moreThanOnce;
```

Or using `BitSet`s (it looks not so elegant, because `BitSet` is not immutable):

```
BitSet atLeastOnce = new BitSet();
BitSet moreThanOnce = new BitSet();
for (BitSet current: sets) {
    BitSet moreThanOnceInCurrent = (BitSet) atLeastOnce.clone();
    moreThanOnceInCurrent.and(current);
    moreThanOnce.or(moreThanOnceInCurrent);
    atLeastOnce.or(current);
}
atLeastOnce.andNot(moreThanOnce);
BitSet justOnce = atLeastOnce;
```

Comment: I was trying the same with `exactlyOnce`, rather than `atLeastOnce`, but your solution is definitely cleaner

Comment: Replace `int` by `BitSet`, or just assume an abstract model where `int`s are arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 1):

```
int length = 5;
int count[] = new int[length];
for (i = 0; i < bitset.length(); i++) {   
    int value = bitset[i];
    unsigned int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {           // until all bits are zero
        if ((value & 1) == 1)     // check lower bit
            count[j]++;
        value >>= 1;              // shift bits, removing lower bit
    }
}

int number = 00000;
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    if (count[k] == 1) 
         number = number | 1; 
    number >>= 1;
}

number is desired answer
```